# Controling Windows 8 Metro Start Menu

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

If I want to develop an App or service that can control Windows 8 Metro Menu(Adding tiles, removing tiles, arranging tiles ,,, etc).

Does something like this available now or not? And if it's from where should I start?

Comment: There is no interface for manipulating tiles in this way. The user controls their tile arrangement. (Imagine how such an interface would be abused! Every app would move themselves to the front and delete the tiles of their competitors.)

Comment: Does there is any way to simulate keystroke like arrows, mouse clicks or mouse scroll on the start menu without using the mouse or the keyboard??

Comment: Ooh sorry I haven't read it carefully. You are right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, mate. I know exactly what you want. But, no.